# Как проверить, является ли упомянутый участник самим собой(discord.py)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

проверка на бота: if member.bot id True:

проверка на самого себя?
пример без проверки:
waysset поприветствовал waysset

пример с проверкой:
waysset, вы не можете упомянуть самого себя!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приводите пример того, как сами пытались решить задачу, пожалуйста.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    elif message.content.startswith("!hello"): # команда
        if message.author == message.mentions[0]: # является ли пользователь самим собой
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, вы не можете упомянуть самого себя!")
        else:
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} поприветствовал {message.mentions[0].mention}")
```